# Sort String Data Numerically (ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, numeric

I've got a gridview with column containing the following rows of data:

```
    1
    2a
    2b
    6
    8a
    10a
```

The header of the column has a sortExpression so I can click to sort it

If I do sort this data, I get it in this order:

```
    1
    10a
    2a
    2b
    6
    8a
```

..where the 10a row comes up because of the 1

I want it to sort numerically, but my values are strings.
The data needs to sort by number and then by the letter at the end (if a letter is there)

How can I do this for my data the being pulled back from a datasource?
**Keep in mind that this is in a gridview.**

Comment: 6 years later.... what I should have just done here was modify the query instead of trying to do it in the code. Could have easily split the strings (as Ankit said below) into number and letter columns and just did a simple ORDER BY number, letter (of course I didn't really specify that I was using an SQL query to pull the data when I asked this question)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of strings then you can sort them using a custom comparison. Here is some code for it:

```
public static void NumericalSort(List<string> l)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex("([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)");
    l.Sort((a, b) =>
    {
        var ma = rgx.Matches(a);
        var mb = rgx.Matches(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < ma.Count; ++i)
        {
            int ret = ma[i].Groups[1].Value.CompareTo(mb[i].Groups[1].Value);
            if (ret != 0)
                return ret;

            ret = int.Parse(ma[i].Groups[2].Value) - int.Parse(mb[i].Groups[2].Value);
            if (ret != 0)
                return ret;
        }

        return 0;
    });
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> l = new string[] { "1", "2a", "2b", "6", "8a", "10a" }.ToList();

    NumericalSort(l);

    foreach (var item in l)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example of how I could implement this into a gridview?

Answer (score 0):

split the number and string and you can achieve what you want

Comment: Into two different columns? I want to be able to sort with it in the same column

Answer (score 0):

CodeProject has one that I use occasionally.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx

Comment: Still not sure how to implement that into a gridview